# Непонятно где ошибка - invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу что-то типо кликера, в этой функции ошибка, не могу найти в чем именно.
Если нужен полный код, могу дать, но он на 145 строк.
Все переменные существуют, в том числе lbl, shop и message.

```
def xtw():
    global x
    global click

    if x==1 and click==200 or click>200:
        print("using X2")
        message.configure(text="использовано X2")
        x = 2
        lbl.configure(text=int(click)
        shop.configure(text="X3") < Invalid syntax.
```

Comment: `lbl.configure(text=int(click)    )`  скобку закройте.

Answer (score 2):

```
def xtw():
    global x
    global click

    if x==1 and click==200 or click>200:
        print("using X2")
        message.configure(text="использовано X2")
        x = 2
        lbl.configure(text=int(click))            # Забыл вторую скобку
        shop.configure(text="X3") < Invalid syntax.
```